# count number of numbers (not digits) in a string

Tags: r, regex

I want to count the number of numbers (not digits) in a string that are separated by spaces.

```
tst1 = "69 21 -" 
tst2 = "69 24 7"
## ATTEMPT: 
grep('([0-9])', tst1, perl = TRUE) ## EXPECT 2
grep('([0-9])', tst2, perl = TRUE) ## EXPECT 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `str_count` function from the `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
str_count(tst1, '\\d+')
2
str_count(tst2, '\\d+')
3
```

Comment: Just a note this is a wrapper for `stringi::stri_count_regex`, which can be used identically.

Answer (score 1):

using `gsub`, extract only digits and count them using `sum()`

Data:

```
tst1  <- list( "69 21 -" , "69 24 7", "sdfsdf 24 453 35 sdff 45", "sfsdff" )
```

Code:

```
y <- lapply(tst1, function(x) {
  temp <- unlist( strsplit( gsub("[^[:digit:]]", " ", x), split = " ") )
  sum( temp != "" )
} )
```

Output:

```
y
# [1] 2 3 4 0
```

Comment: `lengths(regmatches(tst1,gregexpr("\\d+",tst1)))`

Comment: `nchar(gsub("\\d+\\D*",1,trimws(gsub("\\D+"," ",tst1))))`