# How to calculate the number of occurrence of a given NUMBER in each row of a column of strings?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data.frame where certain variables contain a text string. My goal is to count the number of unique occurrences of a given NUMBER in each individual string.

Other posts indicate that this can be accomplished via stringer
[How to calculate the number of occurrence of a given character in each row of a column of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427385/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-given-character-in-each-row-of-a)
[calculate the total number of occurrence of a list of keyword in a string column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876568/calculate-the-total-number-of-occurrence-of-a-list-of-keyword-in-a-string-column)
[count number of numbers (not digits) in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289908/count-number-of-numbers-not-digits-in-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Such as...
Example 1:

```
q.data <- data.frame(number=1:4, 
                     string=c("1", "12", "3", "31"))

stringr::str_count(q.data$string, c("1")) 

# gives (1,1,0,1)
```

This gives `c(1,1,0,1)`. What I really want is to create a new column that is `c(1)` indicating that the number "1" appeared once. I want to then expand this to include multiple keywords such as

Example 2:

```
stringr::str_count(q.data$string, c("1", "31"))
```

This new column would now be `c(2)` indicating that these numbers appeared twice.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: It'll help if you show your desired output with its structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table`:

```
# load library and convert to data.table
setDT(q.data)

# Count occurrences of "1":
q.data[string %in% "1", .N] # string == "1" could have been used too

# Count occurrences of values in a vector:
q.data[string %in% c("1", "31"), .N]
```

The `.N` counts the number of rows. The expression before the comma filters the data. The `%in%` bit checks that elements are included in another set.

Check `?data.table` and `?match` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your strings-to-check in a list and then use `sapply`. Not sure what output structure you want but anyways here's a start -

```
checklist <- list("1", c("1", "31"))

sapply(checklist, function(x) {
  sum(x %in% q.data$string)
})

[1] 1 2
```